# Try to parse buffer as PE with IDAPython

Tags: idapython, pe, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

file_buffer = requests.get(file_url)

buf_size = len(file_buffer)

pe_file = pefile.PE(data=file_buffer)

print("This is really a pe imphash %s." % pe_file.get_imphash())

addr = hex(id(file_buffer))

print("PE start memory at %s length %d." % (addr, len(file_buffer)))

new_loader = ida_idaapi.loader_input_t()

mem_inp = ida_diskio.create_memory_linput(addr, buf_size)

Comment: Your code is broken. What is `addr`?

Comment: ea_t - I cant' this parameter right in python @RolfRolles

Comment: Right. Well, your code snippet shows no definition for that variable, so we don't know what you did wrong. Nobody can help you until you show us how you defined the `addr` variable.

Comment: buffer = b'\xB8\x01\x00\x00\x00'
id(addr) - will be the start address of the buffer thank you for your help

Comment: Man, if you want help, paste the real code into your question, not pseudocode, not snippets that you think are relevant, the whole thing.

Comment: @RolfRolles Posted the code, thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

After some research time, I found a way to do it in CPP but not in python.

https://github.com/SentineLabs/Memloader/blob/main/MemoryLoader/MemoryLoader/MemoryLoader.cpp

The most relevant part of the code dealing with loading PEs from buffer to memory:

```
void destroy_linput(linput_t* li)
{
    close_linput(li);
}

linput_t* create_linput(std::vector< bit7z::byte_t >& file_buffer)
{
    return create_bytearray_linput(file_buffer.data(), file_buffer.size());
}

void destroy_linfos(load_info_t* linfos)
{
    free_loaders_list(linfos);
}

load_info_t* create_linfos(linput_t* li)
{
    return build_loaders_list(li, "");
}

const unique_ptr_s1<linput_t, destroy_linput> li2{
  create_linput(file_buffer)
};
        
const unique_ptr_s1<load_info_t, destroy_linfos> linfos{
  create_linfos(li2.get())
};
```