# IDAPython, parse IDA DB as PE file

Tags: binary-analysis, idapython, pe, idapro-sdk, ida-plugin

[image]

I have buffer loaded into IDA with IDAPython in a costume loader script, I want to now to be parsed as a PE, or in fact, it would be better if IDA will try to reparse it as a PE, is it possible without opening a new IDA instance / another DB?
As you can see I have the right raw data loaded, but for some reason, there is no processing on the data that a loaded.

Comment: I have answered the question here (https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26661/try-to-parse-buffer-as-pe-with-idapython/27363#27363)
This is a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

I don't think IDA handle multiple PE instance, one of the solution I used in the past was to create a new segment, load the .text and ask IDA to decompile this segment.